# AC/DC transformer and isolation

Tags: transformer, ac-dc

My theoretical knowledge from engineering school is a little bit rusty, and I am not working in this field so I have not been practicing in a long time.

But I asked myself a question that I can't solve, and now I am doubting everything I thought I knew... so sorry if that seems silly...

Say I have an AC/DC transformer rated 15V 5.4W used to recharge an hair trimmer's battery. The appliance has no ground. I wanted to know if it can leak current and how much.

First I simply tried to measure the current between any of the +/- wires of the output of the transformer and the ground, but I kept reading 0A. Then I found this:

[image]

https://www.powerelectronictips.com/the-basics-of-ac-line-isolation-for-safety-part-2-the-solution/

Is it what's happening? There is no current leak in my case because the circuit is open when I link any of the +/- DC output wires to the ground? a simple AC/DC transformer acts as isolating transformer?

Comment: Yes, note there's no such thing as an AC-DC transformer, but there are AC-DC converter circuits and they often use transformers in them.

Comment: You are right, I understood it with this https://learn.adafruit.com/power-supplies/transformer-based-ac-dc-converters

Comment: so if the ac-dc converter works properly, you can't get electrified, right?

Comment: @hymced Yes, and no. You shouldn't get a shock if you only touch one side of the supply's output, but if you contact both sides simultaneously then you will still experience a shock.

Comment: haha yes I understand, I was just thinking that I needed to clarify my question, but you answered both cases! why do you guys post in comment instead of answers? :)

Comment: So why are there reports of people getting shocked by their phone chargers while in bath? The only explanation I can find is that it was defective and isolation between windings broken, am I correct?

Comment: @hymced Yes, something like that would be due to a faulty power supply. (though you could get a small shock through the filter capacitors even on something working properly!) I would avoid using any electronics in the bath, personally, but if you have to, definitely use something battery powered, not anything plugged into the wall.

Comment: AFAIK, isolation on/between windings on that voltage level would be expressed by values above 25MegaOhms (or 100M-500M, including exceptional circumstances and surroundings parameters, e.g. temperature, humidity) and might be calculated from leakage current between primary and isolated windings sides. Primary safety features should be installed (depends on country's regulations) and devices checked for physical integrity. yes "use something battery powered"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is inside your device as it could be either a classic low-frequency transformer followed by a diode bridge or a switching converter - a SMPS - featuring a high-frequency transformer and an optocoupler for regulation purposes. The low-frequency transformer should be in a bulky and "heavy" enclosure while the switching version should be a light and small enclosure.

The transformer is meant to permanently sustain a specific voltage before its dielectric strength is exceeded. As the operating voltage is well below this limit, it ensures a safe operation for the user who will touch the end connector. However, the transformer, as any component, is affected by parasitics like inter-winding capacitance. As you perhaps remember, a capacitor offers an impedance when subjected to an ac voltage (50 or 60 Hz). As such, some leakage current may flow between the ground of the output connector and the earth.

Now, for noise pollution reasons, switching power supply designers often install one or two so-called Y-capacitors (usually a blue disc) between the primary-side (non isolated) and the secondary-side (isolated). These capacitors are there to limit the amount of common-mode parasitics below a regulatory level:

[image]

As any capacitor, they will authorize the circulation of current under an ac bias and will add to that of the transformer. The total leakage current is limited by the IEC-950 standard which thus sets the maximum capacitance designers can use.

People can feel this leakage current when it exceeds some threshold. It depends on the skin resistance and the environment. It did push Nokia, years ago, to force their ac-dc charger manufacturers to get rid of the Y-cap because of the "shaving" effect, meaning phone users could feel the tickling current on their cheek while phoning with mobiles having a metal enclosure. If the leakage current is significant, then an ac current measurement between any of the output terminals should give a value but in the range of tens of µA. Not more otherwise it would indicate a potential safety issue. Perhaps with your hair trimmer, as it may be used in a wet environment, there is a reinforced insulation and the leakage is extremely small.

Comment: thank you, it is very instructive! you say tens of micro amps, but it could be up to 250 micro amps as per the standard right?

Comment: Oui, it depends on the Y-capacitor value they used (if any) and on the transformer construction. Also, but it is not your case, when you stack consumer equipment on the same outlet, it is not unusual to feel the current from one of the chassis because the leakage currents add up. If you set your multimeter in V ac mode, what voltage do you measure between any of the dc output wires and ground/earth? Further reading [here](https://slpower.com/App-slpower/images/whitepapers/An113%20Leakage%20Current.pdf).

Comment: 0.0V on VAC but my multimeter has only 2 calibers in AC: 600V and 200V.

Answer (score 0):

First, your electronic device does not need ground as it might be double insulated (Class II) appliances. There are at least two types of layers of insulation.
Second, as the name of the transformer indicates, it is isolated so that you would see neither harmonics nor transients.

Comment: I did not say I had an isolating transformer, its just a picture I found. I mentioned an AC/DC converter, that's all. My question could also be: is an AC/DC converter with a transformer always isolating?

Answer (score 0):

### For the record, those people are dangerously wrong

First, that graphic was done by nitwits, and is wrong.  The nitwits are relying on the concept of "first ground fault is free" when dealing with an isolated AC output.  That is, if you are the only contact to an isolated AC power loop, there's no circuit to complete, so no current flows.  **WRONG! That doesn't work in the real world** where unexpected stuff happens.

Yeah, the first ground fault is free, but the first ground fault *may already have happened* and you're the second one, so you're dead.  You have no earthly way of knowing whether the first one has happened.  The method is allowed in highly controlled industrial environments where engineering staff is routinely checking for that "first ground fault" having happened.  In all other applications, it has been proven by accident data that the far safer thing is to *intentially create the first fault* by bonding the center conductor to earth.

Center conductor being [120V center on 120/240V North American](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=266) split-phase, neutral on European 230V derived from 400V 3-phase "wye", and center point on UK 110V construction power and Philippine old-world 220V.  Tapping the center assures the lowest **live-earth** voltage possible on all the conductors, e.g. 55V on UK construction sites and 110V in Philippines and North America.

### However, for low voltage, it's fine.

However, when the output side of the transformer is low-voltage such as 15 volts, then there is nothing wrong with the method.  Yes, there may already be a second ground fault, and yes, you may get shocked... but you'll get shocked with 15 volts, which is such a low voltage that no appreciable current will move through your body, unless you embed the contacts subcutaneously in your skin.  (the one time a guy managed to die from ~12 volts).